# UnityException: GetActiveScene is not allowed to be called from a MonoBehaviour constructor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors, 3d, scene-manager

I'm trying to make a save level system and I keep on getting this error.

> UnityException: GetActiveScene is not allowed to be called from a MonoBehaviour constructor

I've tried searching this up, but there were no results. Here is the code I used:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class EndLevel : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PlayerMovement pm;

    public GameObject completeLevelUI;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start() { 
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collisionInfo) {
        if(collisionInfo.collider.tag == "Finish") {
            Debug.Log("You beat the level!");
            pm.enabled = false;
            completeLevelUI.SetActive(true);
            Level = Level + 1;
            PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("Level", Level);
            Debug.Log("Saved");
            Invoke("NextLevel", 3);
        }
    }

    public void NextLevel() {
        SceneManager.LoadScene (SceneManager
            .GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
    }
}
```

Any Ideas about the error?

Comment: Probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60662859/7111561 ..  are you sure the error is caused by the code you provide? Or: Are you maybe destroying this GameObject somewhere else? In that case the `NextLevel` tries to be invoked on an instance that is no longer valid

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the current active Scene in the [`Start()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html) or [`Awake()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html) methods.

**Example with [`Start()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html):**

```cs
private int sceneNumber;

private void Start() {
    sceneNumber = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
}
```

As an alternative solution you could also use a Lazzy Getter. Which means that the value won't get stale between when the scene loads and when you use it, which might matter with other pieces of data.

**Example with Lazzy Getter:**

```cs
private int sceneNumber { 
    get { 
        return SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex; 
    }
}
```

---

When you use either of those solutions, you can now simply call `scenenumber + 1` in your [`SceneManager.Load()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html) function call instead.

Additionally you need to ensure that you are calling an [`IEnumerator`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html), instead of Invoking the Function call. If you want to delay the scene loading.

**Function Call:**

```cs
private void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collisionInfo) {
    ...
    StartCoroutine(NextLevel(3f));
    ...
}

private IEnumerator NextLevel(float seconds) {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(seconds);
    SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneNumber + 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I still keep getting the error. Any Ideas?

Comment: The start method

Comment: It starts by saying that GetActiveScene cannot be called in monobehavior.

Comment: What do you mean?